# Hardware architecture for power

Tags: power

I have a fairly simple circuit with an MCU and few N-mosfets for controlling RGB LED strip.

[image: layout]

Available voltage is 24 V. Same will power up the LED strip. I need to use the same line to power up the MCU which works on 3.3 V.

My peak mosfet current requirement might go up to 15 amps and I am constrained by size so I cant use heat sinks. As such I want to go ahead with mosfets with low RDSon (about 3-4 milli-ohms). To achieve such low RDSon, gate drive voltage should be about 10 V. 5 V can also work but the RDSon will be 1-2 milli-ohms higher as compared to 10 V drive.

**Architecture-1**

I use MC34063 IC to convert 24 V to 5 V line. Use an LDO to convert 5 V to 3.3 V for MCU and further use a voltage level shifter between MCU and mosfet to drive the mosfet with a 5 V signal.

Pros - Relatively simpler power tree architecture. Cheaper.

Cons - I miss out on driving the mosfet with 10 V signal which might cause more heating in the mosfets.

**Architecture - 2**

Use MC34063 IC to convert 24 V to 10 V. Use linear regulator to convert 10 V to 3.3 V.

Challenge - There are no (in reasonable price range) level shifters which convert a 3.3 V signal to 10 V signal. I might have to implement it using discrete components.

**Architecture - 3**

24 V -> MC34063 -> 5 V -> LDO -> 3.3 V

Besides this, I use a zener regulator or a voltage divider (2K + 2K) and generate 12 V. I use a transistor to feed this higher voltage to mosfet gates. I am using a resistive voltage divider because mosfets need very low current to turn ON, which can be provided by the voltage divider or the zener regulator.

Which one should I choose? Is there a better approach to this problem at hand?

Comment: Doesn't it take current to charge the FET gate capacitance?  I'd think that would take option 3 out of the running.

Comment: @JRE - yeah. I meant, it will take very low current which can be provided by the voltage divider. I will edit it to make more correct. :)

Comment: Can you drive the MOSFETs with 24V? That would be even simpler.

Comment: Presuming your Mosfets adjust current, they will dissipate a lot of heat as this works in practise by creating a voltage drop over the MOSFET. Also in a DC/DC converter charging the gate capacitance is a major source of losses, the more the highter the fsw is. You should add circuit diagram, it's not clear what the application looks like.

Comment: *There are no (in reasonable price range) level shifters which convert a 3.3 V signal to 10 V signal*.  There are tons of "gate driver" IC's that do this and cost less than $1.00.  If that is too expensive then your cost constraint is prohibitively low.

Comment: @LiorBilia - Not feasible. They might be available but at a higher cost or with more RDSon.

Comment: @LiorBilia 20V is much more common Vgs rating than 30V thought. Various simple circuits are possible to limit the Vgs, e.g. a humble zener diode or a straight resistor divider.

Comment: _Challenge - There are no (in reasonable price range) level shifters which convert a 3.3 V signal to 10 V signal. I might have to implement it using discrete components._

You make it sound like discretes are a bad thing.. ubiquitous bc847 NPN transistor costs pennies and will happily work as a pull-down for 10V gate voltage. You can set up a resistor divider to create 10V and pull it down to switch Mosfet off. TI lists almost 300 integrated DC/DC parts capable of 28->3.3V conversion, certainly you can find something suitable.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack how often do you need to switch that MOSFET?

Comment: @marcus - Since it's RGB strip, it will either be kept on or at PWM for 3-8 hours a day.

Comment: This device will shift from 3V to 10V and costs $0.99.  Why can't you use that?   http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002052D.pdf

Comment: what's the PWM speed? Seriously, you should really define this in your question!

Comment: @everyone - looks like I need to post this question with more details. I am going to update it. give me few minutes. sorry and thank you

Comment: Made the changes

Comment: are the six channels independent in terms of PWM, or are they all dimmed by the same amount?

Comment: all are independent.

Comment: Dioes Inc has a reasonable selection of 30V parts with < 4 m Ohm at Vgs = 4.5V. https://www.diodes.com/products/discrete/mosfets/mosfet-master-table/n-channel/n-channel-30v/

Comment: I agree with @scorpdaddy. Here is another chip suggestion: MIC4127: 0.75€ (qty 1 at mouser) for a *dual* gate driver. Put three of them to get your 6 channels, you have a hassle-free solution for 2.25€. If it is still too expensive, you should tell us how you define "reasonable price range", and you need to be aware that any solution made out of discrete will probably be more expensive and less performant.

Comment: @petersmith - is 30 V rated mosfet good/safe for 24 V application? I was going with 40 V rated ones to be on the safe side. But again I don't know how much additional margin to take.

Comment: IPC-9592 says 90% for DS voltage and current and 80% for power dissipation and the GS voltage. So, yes, 30V is perfectly fine for 24V with 80% derating for DS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably be best served with an 10V LDO for the gate drive (or fixed 12V if you like) with 2k2 pull-up resistor and using cheap BC847 NPN transistors to pull down the FET gates.

5kHz PWM is not nothing, i.e. 200µs total cycle time. To give yourself a reasonable duty cycle range, you should aim for 10µs rise time or less, which works out to 95% duty cycle max. You should steer clear from large gate charge mosfets for this or alternatively chop your PWM to e.g. 500Hz. 10nC @ 10V gate charge MOSFET would reach ~9V gate voltage in about 5µs if you use 2.2k pull-up resistor to 10V.

For the µCU, use an integrated switch buck converter, these start at about £0.5 single piece for something that can handle 24V input. Using LDO would cause punitive dissipation in the LDO, even for modest current drain. Using Texas Instruments makes life easier if you're not comfortable designing SMPS circuits as their webench tool walks you through it. You're looking at ca. £1.2 for single piece for e.g. TPS54233 thought.

When designing the SMPS, do bear in mind the ceramic capacitor DC bias, you would really want electrolytic for the input capacitor as the bias will rob an MLCC most of it's capacitance.

**Update**

The LDO will dissipate non-zero amounts of heat when all LEDs are off. With 2k2 pull-down resistors the maximum power dissipation (=duty cycle 0%) will be about 0.5W. When using 10V LDO: $$\frac{10V}{2200R}*8*14V = 509mW$$

Comment: LDO for creating 10 V is genius. Better yet, I can convert 24 V to 15 V which ensures low RDS and still at 75 % of max VGS allowed. It also produces lesser heating in my LDO. Pullups on all gates and some cheap mosfets/transistors to pull the gate LOW (of the main mosfet).

Comment: In the last paragraph, you mentioned about input capacitors. Can you please show me a pic which capacitor you mean? Is it the bulk capacitor being used at the Vin pin of any switching IC?

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Yes, the input capacitor. That capacitor sees 24V so for example Murata 4.7µF 35V X7R 0805 capacitor would function as 1µF cap. Going a step bigger doesn't help that much as 10µF 35V X6S 1206 cap functions as 1.5µF, the dielectric matters a lot so you want X7R/X7S. You did mention size constraint so you may have to put up with it so factor it into the SMPS design. Presuming your microprocessor takes 1W or less it's probably fine using 0805 4.7µF X7R/X7S there as it can certainly handle the input ripple current. Electrolytic can would work if it fits but beware of ESR and Iripple.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will keep this in mind. I can use electrolytic. Should I use two in parallel to reduce ESR?

Comment: @Whiskeyjack It's not so much the ESR as it's the ripple current capacity, althought they go hand-in-hand. As long as it can handle the input ripple it's fine.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack, by the way, while the power dissipation of a single LED is small, these add up. With 15V LDO you'd be looking at ~7mA per gate being pulled low, ~55mA total worst case. This in turn means 55mA * 9V = ~0.5W power dissipation in the LDO. You can't use small a SOT23 LDO and expect it to survive. Slightly unintuitively worst case is when you actually power down the LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

Considering switch-mode regulator ICs are cheap and can be made to work with few external components, why not simply have two? One directly for the microcontroller (unless you do  sensitive analog measurements, that will not suffer under being directly driven from a SMPS), and one for the gate driver.

You could sensibly drive both directly from the 24 V; that would be a sensible way of getting errors isolated better, which might be desirable.

If you're space-constrained, the MC34063 is not the controller of choice: It switches at only up to 100 kHz, which means that for the same power, you'd need a relatively large inductor, compared to what modern SMPS controllers can do in frequency (upwards of 400 kHz, up to single-digit MHz).

If cost is not an issue, use integrated buck modules; for example, TI has [such](http://www.ti.com/power-management/non-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulators/step-down-buck/buck-modules-integrated-inductor/products.html#p238min=2.2;20&p238max=28;60&p634min=0.25;10&p634max=10;24&p451max=1;2&p212max=51.690821256038646;100).

If you're concerned about cost, there's many modern switch-mode regulators by [TI](http://www.ti.com/power-management/non-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulators/step-down-buck/buck-converter-integrated-switch/products.html#p238max=24;100&p236typ=0.0003;100) or by ONsemi, or *many* other companies. Their integrated switch transistors are typically lower-loss than that of the "classic" MC34063, which means that they dissipate less heat.

Comment: An integrated switch supply is a good compromise between cost and ease of use. Texas has a very nice webench tool that makes designing an SMPS almost too easy. e.g. TPS5432 would certainly be capable of 24-to-3.3V. Texas is not the cheapest (£1.3 each) but you can use their design tool with another manufacturer's controller as long as you know what you're doing..

Comment: Oops, TPS5432 is a 6V part, I meant TPS5423x converters.